# why do I get segmentation fault error every time I run this program?

Tags: c++

every time I run this program I get a segmentation fault error and I can't figure out why. The function is to sort an array and this code does that but every time I try to run it I get an error that says segmentation fault core dumped.

```
#include <iostream>

void counting_sort(int *array, unsigned array_len) {
  int output[array_len];
  int max;
  for (int i = 0; i < array_len; i++) {
    if (array[i] > max) {
      max = array[i];
    }
  }
  int count[max + 1];
  for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    count[i] = 0;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < array_len; i++) {
    count[array[i]]++;
  }
  for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    count[i] += count[i - 1];
  }
  for (int i = array_len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    output[count[array[i]] - 1] = array[i];
    count[array[i]]--;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < array_len; i++) {
    array[i] = output[i];
  }
  std::cout << array[1];
}

} // namespace cs19
int main() {
  int num = 3;
  int arr[num];
  arr[0] = 4;
  arr[1] = 2;
  arr[2] = 7;
  counting_sort(arr, num);
  return 0;
}
```

Can anybody tell me why this is happening and how to fix it? I am somewhat new to coding so I am struggling to figure out what is causing this.

Comment: Debug this line : output[count[array[i]] - 1] = array[i];  are you sure the index calculated is always >0. 2 More things, initialize your arrays (C++ will not set entries to 0 automatically). And arr[num] with variable length is not standard C++ (some compilers accept it as extension). The length of a C++ array should always be a constant. If variable length is needed use std::vector

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can run the program at your speed and watch exactly what the computer does with the program s it does it. Typical usage is to step through the problem region in the code (or the whole program if you have no idea where to look) line-by-line with an eye out for the unexpected like the wrong value being stored or the wrong path being taken.

Comment: It may be a good idea to use Valgrind tool. It should show memory violation issue on the source code level. Caveat: works only on Linux. On Windows works under WSL

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard the size of a C++ array must be **compile time constant**.

So you cannot have

```
int num = 5;
int MyArray[num]; // incorrect
```

The correct way to do this is:

```
const int num = 5;
int MyArray[num]; // correct
```

This is only one of the problem in your example code. You have done this twice in the code. First for the array named `arr` inside main and then for the array named `output` inside the called function. Similarly for the array named `count`.

**The problem is** that you have `max` as a *built-in* local variable and you haven't initialized it explicitly. So it will have a *garbage value*.

You can use `std::vector` for the purpose where the size is determined at runtime. The [below](https://onlinegdb.com/uEAqJ-II8) working example shows your implementation using `std::vector` instead of built in array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
void counting_sort(std::vector<int> &vec) {
    std::vector<int> output(vec.size());
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        if (vec[i] > max) {
            max = vec[i];
        }
    }
    std::vector<int> count(max +1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        count[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        count[vec[i]]++;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    }
    for (int i = vec.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        output[count[vec[i]] - 1] = vec[i];
        count[vec[i]]--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        vec[i] = output[i];
    }
    //std::cout << vec[1];
}


int main() {
    int num = 3;
    std::vector<int> myvec(num);
    myvec[0] = 4;
    myvec[1] = 2;
    myvec[2] = 7;
    
    std::cout<<"before sorting: "<<std::endl;
    for(const int &i: myvec)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
    }
    //sort the vector by calling the counting_sort function
    counting_sort(myvec);
    
    std::cout<<"after sorting: "<<std::endl;
    for(const int &i: myvec)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`max` variable is not initialized. Initialize it to 0 and should work as expected. This works different in `release` and `no-opt` (debug) mode.

change

```
int max;
```

to

```
int max=0;
```

If `max` variable is not initialized, value will be undefined. That means `count` array will be created with 2342525 or some similar range and cause problems.